# css position label text in the true center (vertical and horizontal) without moving the label

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use CSS to position text of a label in the exact center of a  control. The CSS below still leaves the text at the top of the label. Any ideas please?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HFJ6V/1/)

CSS

```
.plate_well {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: 15px;   /* this doesnt do anything ?? */
    font-size: 7pt;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;

}
```

HTML

```
<label class="plate_well" id="foo">bar</label>
```

(I also have the issue of IE being unable to render curves but that's a separate question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `line-height: 30px;` to center a single line of text instead. The `30px` needs to be the same value as the height of the element you wish to vertically center text in.

**Note:** The fiddle has `height:40px` whereas the code in question has `height:30px`. Just choose the `line-height` to match the height.

[`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) would actually moving the entire `<label>` (and text) down but only applies to inline-level and table-cell elements. It is not applying in your case as the `<label>` is floated.